# how to print table in CLI

Tags: c++, c, ansi-c

I use some code like this to print a table

```
print "\t1%s\t2%s\t3%s\t4%s", str1, str2, str3, str4
```

But, some str width a little long, it output like this

```
1blabla   2blabla   3blabla  4blabla
1blablablabla       2blabla  3blabla  4blabla
```

Any better way to format these strings?

Comment: Try `std::setw` in `<iomanip>`.

Comment: What would be better? truncating the strings or finding the length of the longest string in the set before you ever print any output?

Comment: What the heck kind of language is this?  Visual Basic?

Comment: Are you working in *C*? Or *C++*? String handling is very different between the two.

Answer (score 1):

First, for each column, determine the maximum length required to display each element, e.g. by iterating over the column entries and finding the maximum `strlen()`. Then, for each row, print the corresponding column entries and pad with spaces as necessary.

Here's a pretty-printer in C that takes a 2D array of pointers to strings (where each "row" is `NULL`-terminated and the last row consists of all `NULL`s):

```
void print_pretty(char ***arr)
{
    int i, j, cols;

    /* count columns */
    j = cols = 0;
    while (arr[0][j++]) cols++;

    /* init column sizes */
    size_t sizes[cols];
    for (j = 0; j < cols; sizes[j++]=0);

    /* 1st pass: calculate column widths */
    for (i = 0; arr[i][0]; i++)
            for (j = 0; arr[i][j]; j++)
                    if (strlen(arr[i][j]) > sizes[j])
                            sizes[j] = strlen(arr[i][j]);

    /* 2nd pass: print table */
    for (i = 0; arr[i][0]; i++) {
            for (j = 0; arr[i][j]; j++)
                    printf("%-*2$s ", arr[i][j], sizes[j]);
            puts("");
    }
}
```

The ugliest part is the C99 variable size array and the format specifier in the call to `printf()`. Also, you can optimize away one `strlen()`.

Output looks like this:

```
foo   bar   baz 
snafu fubar x
```

Comment: `std::string::length` would be a better option than `strlen`.

Comment: @chris: Good point! I was referring to the "C" tag, having little experience with C++.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the maximum length of the strings at compile time, you can simply indicate that length with a `printf()` format specifier:

```
printf("%12s %12s %12s %12s\n", str1, str2, str3, str4);
```

Or with a C++ stream manipulator:

```
#include <iomanip>
...
cout << setw(12) << str1 << ... << '\n';
```

This also allows you to pass the column width at runtime, if you want variable-width columns. You can do so with `printf()`, too, by changing the format specifier and passing the length before the string:

```
printf("%*s ...\n", str1.length(), str1, ...);
```

It’s considered poor style to mix `stdio` code and `iostream` code in C++, but the latter is generally preferable unless it makes your code unreadably verbose.